# Is this proof rigorous?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

"There is no rational number whose square is $\displaystyle \frac{m}{n}$, where $\displaystyle \frac{m}{n}$ is a positive fraction in lowest terms, unless $m$ and $n$ are perfect squares. For suppose, if possible, that
$\displaystyle \frac{p^2}{q^2} = \displaystyle \frac{m}{n}$, $p$ having no factor in common with $q$ and $m$ no factor in common with
n. Then $np^2 = mq^2$. Every factor of $q^2$ must divide $np^2$ and, as $p$ and $q$ have no common factor, every factor of $q$ must divide $n$. Hence $n=rq^2$ where $r$ is an integer. But this involves $m = rp^2$; and as $m$ and $n$ have no common factor, $r$ must be unity. Thus $m = p^2$, $n = q^2$, as was to be proved. In particular, it follows by taking $m = 2$, $n = l$ that $2$ cannot be the square of a rational number."

A part of this proof strikes me as odd:

"Hence $n=rq^2$ where $r$ is an integer. But this involves $m = rp^2$; and as $m$ and $n$ have no common factor, $r$ must be unity."

The use of $r$ as a factor for both $n$ and $m$ requires a presupposition that $r$ is unity. Without this knowledge, the writer would need to assume two distinct variables, instead of just $r$. The proof seemed logically continuous prior to this bit, so I'm looking for second opinions.

I'm working through this book (G. H. Hardy's 'A Course of Pure Mathematics') without guidance or consultation (excepting the fine folk on the internet), and little more than a broken, North American public school level education. The very 'general' mode of explanation Hardy uses here is leading me to spend an awful lot of time second-guessing myself.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of formatting; I typed this on a smartphone.

Comment: The quoted sentence should say but this **implies**. From $n=rq^2$ we get by susbstitution that $rq^2p^2=mq^2$. and therefore by cancellation $m=rp^2$. There is no presupposition of any kind. But soon there is the conclusion that $r$ is $1$.

Comment: Second-guessing yourself is great! That is an excellent way to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\frac{p^2}{q^2} = \frac{m}{n}$, then $np^2 = mq^2$, so if it is the case that $n = rq^2$, then $mq^2 = rq^2p^2$, and dividing through by $q^2$ yields that $m = rp^2$.